# In Swiftui, how to minimize passing functions to sub-views

Tags: swiftui

I am working on a todo app that interacts with an API to store data. My view structure looks like this (simplified):

```
ContentView: List of { ProjectView }
ProjectView: List of { TaskView }
```

The `ContentView` has a `webServer` variable that provides functions like `storeTask(task: Task)` and `deleteTask(task: Task)`.

So now I want my `TaskView` to be able to modify tasks. The most straightforward pattern seems to provide `storeTask` and `deleteTask` to `TaskView` to keep the view ignorant of the implementation details. That means that I have to pass these two functions through the whole tree of sub-views: `ContentView -> ProjectView -> TaskView`. But then, a minor change in function signature requires a changes for every view that's part of the view hierarchy.

This feels like an inefficient pattern as it's already complex for the simple app I am building. What are other approaches? For context, I remember this same issue from working on React, and using approaches like Redux to deal with this. I'm wondering whether there's a standard approach for simplifying this in SwiftUI?

Comment: Extract functions into view model class and just pass instance of view model through view hierarchy in any appropriate way.

Comment: I recently made a GitHub project outlining SwiftUI architecture for a todo app very similar. Take a look at the ItemArrayObject for reference. You probably don't need the extra DataManager layer. (https://github.com/ndsarno/TodoList-MVVM-Advanced) Still a work in progress.

Comment: Thanks @nicksarno looking at it. And yes, happy to make this the answer as well if you propose it, but in either case I'll be looking at the repo to understand this pattern better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common architecture pattern in SwiftUI is MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel). There are many articles online explaining it, but essentially the layers break into:

1. Model - manage a piece of data
2. View - manage the UI
3. ViewModel - manage the data (models) to be displayed in the UI (view)

To answer your question, you would need to create ViewModel layer that manages your data and pass that ViewModel throughout your Views (as @Asperi mentioned in the comments).

Here is a great article explaining MVVM: https://matteomanferdini.com/mvvm-pattern-ios-swift/

Here is one of my Github repo's that uses MVVM Architecture in SwiftUI to make a todo-list app, similar to your project. If you take a look at the ViewModel layers you will find examples of what you're trying to do. https://github.com/ndsarno/TodoList-MVVM-Advanced